# how to use sudo pip3 install --target to install package and recognize the dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, pip

I want to use pip3 to install rise package. I use the command

```
sudo pip3 install rise
```

Then the rise package is installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages and print out:

```
Collecting rise
Downloading rise-4.0.0b1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (359kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 368kB 4.0MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): notebook>=4.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rise)
Installing collected packages: rise
Successfully installed rise
```

Now I want to install rise in different directory, so I write

```
sudo pip3 install --target /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages rise
```

then it print out:

```
Collecting rise
Downloading rise-4.0.0b1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (359kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 368kB 4.8MB/s 
Collecting notebook>=4.2 (from rise)
Downloading notebook-4.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.7MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.7MB 290kB/s 
Collecting nbconvert (from notebook>=4.2->rise)
Downloading nbconvert-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (319kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 327kB 5.8MB/s 
Collecting ipython-genutils (from notebook>=4.2->rise)
Downloading ipython_genutils-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client (from notebook>=4.2->rise)
Downloading jupyter_client-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 16.0MB/s
```

well because I already install notebook nbconvert and other dependencies via apt-get and they satisfies the version requirement. Why pip3 need to reinstall them? But in the first case, without --target, pip3 can recognize all the dependencies. Also, if I just use

```
pip3 install rise
```

pip3 also not recognize all the dependencies and will download all of them. I want to ask what is the default searching path of dependencies in pip3. If pip3 can not recognize the searching path of dependencies, how to tell it?